# How to make sure pressed button remain "pressed down"

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using BootStrap Group Button class and found that in my own code, if a button is pressed down, the button will pop up back in a few seconds....

How can I make sure it remain pressed-down status?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Stage of business:</label>
        <br />
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon">Start-up</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon">Growth Company</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon">Mature Company</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

---

**Update**

I added the active css and 
I found that when I clicked the button the whole page gets refreshed so that's why the button loses active css class.
How to disable the submit action on these 3 button only? Coz I do have a button which is also in this form and it needs to trigger a submit action.

```
$('.btn-stage').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("active"); //addCss("active");
        })
```

---

**Update 3**

**Also, in this button group, only one button can be selected, if other button is selected, then the rest of buttons should bounce back.**

Thank you.

Comment: you know the css class applayed to the button once its pressed ?

Comment: hi @Youness, I checked and didn't find any new css classes were added onto those buttons in Twitter BootStrap website. So ?

Comment: try adding activ and see what it gives

Comment: see my answer hope it helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding an active class to the button should keep it's 'pressed in' style.

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, it still triggers the refresh action, please see my update part, thank you.

Comment: @Franva I have updated my example to show how to stop the buttons default action.

Comment: hi Scott, I found this allows me to select multiple buttons, but I only want to allow user select one button at most.

Comment: @Franva so you're actually looking to disable all the buttons once one is clicked? I obviously misinterpreted your question. Something like this would handle the disabling - http://jsfiddle.net/ct8yukjh - but disabling the buttons will not make them look 'pressed in' but instead greyed out. If however you're looking to make all the buttons look 'pressed in' but not clickable then something more like this is what you're after - http://jsfiddle.net/ct8yukjh/1. it adds the active class to make them look pressed and then unbinds the click function from them.

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/q7cL1dqf/1/)**

js

```
$('.Button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

css

```
.Button:active, .active {
    background-color:red;
    color: white;
}
```

html

```
<button class='Button'>Button</button>
```

---

**[Final Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/q7cL1dqf/2/)**

js

```
$('.Button').click(function(e) {
    $('.Button').not(this).removeClass('active');    
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

html

```
<button class='Button'>Button</button>
<button class='Button'>Button</button>
<button class='Button'>Button</button>
```

css

```
.Button:active, .active {
    background-color:red;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: hi, it still triggers the refresh action, please see my update part, thank you.

Comment: I am able to understand you properly. Can you explain "triggers the refresh action"?

Comment: hi it means the page gets refreshed when clicked a button on it.

Answer (score 1):

add a class to define them lets say "nosubmit" like this :

```
    <button class="btn btn-default nosubmit"><span class="glyphicon">Start-up</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default nosubmit"><span class="glyphicon">Growth Company</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default nosubmit"><span class="glyphicon">Mature Company</span>
    </button>
```

then do this :

```
    $('.nosubmit').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('.nosubmit').unbind( "click" );// this will take off the click handler from all the nosubmit buttons
// if you want it to be to changed back whene you click again use toggleClass instead
         return false;
    });
```

Comment: Hi Youness this code allows user to select multiple buttons, but I only want to allow user select one button at most.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put the buttons? Is it in form? I have no problem add/changing button's class into active if the buttons are not within the form tag. you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn-stage').click(function () {
            $('.btn-stage.active').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        })
    });
```

but if it is in the form tag, you need to add type='button' to your button elements. so it looks like this

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Stage of business:</label>
                    <br />
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-stage" type='button'><span class="glyphicon">Start-up</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-stage" type='button'><span class="glyphicon">Growth Company</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-stage" type='button'><span class="glyphicon">Mature Company</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the javascript above is still working. When you had a button within a form and you don't specify the type of its button, it will automatically set as type='submit'

Comment: yes, I did use button. Please see my post. I cannot say any differences expect you put a form outside everything which I do have as well.

Comment: did you try adding type='button' to your button?

Comment: no, I use button directly. like this <button></button>